# I Can't Get Statistics From Siddhi Query Guide Example

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, siddhi

Recently I started study on siddhi and I want to get statistics from my siddhi runner. I deployed the example from query guide but nothing happened. Here what I used for siddhi

(I copied from here https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/query-guide/#statistics) :

```
@App:name('TestMetrics')
@App:Statistics(reporter = 'console', interval='120')
define stream TestStream (message string);
@info(name='logQuery')
from TestStream#log("Message:")
insert into TempStream;
```

and this is what's showed up on console :

```
[2023-07-17 15:00:09,819]  INFO {io.siddhi.distribution.core.internal.util.SiddhiAppFilesystemInvoker} - Siddhi App: TestMetrics saved in the filesystem
[2023-07-17 15:00:13,465]  INFO {io.siddhi.distribution.core.internal.StreamProcessorService} - Siddhi App TestMetrics deployed successfully
```

I have tried to change interval and includes for metrics but nothing solved my problem. Because of I  copied code from query guide I wonder where is the problem.

UPDATE => I can get those statistics at tooling but still not in the runner. What's the differences between them